# Get data from Ajax Get Request in CherryPy for login session

Tags: jquery, ajax, cherrypy

I'm doing an authentication for an web app in which I have the following flow:

After the Login, a POST is sent calling login method and if login successful redirects to /user

```
@cherrypy.expose
    def login(self, username=None, password=None):

        cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=? and password=?""", (username, password))

        result = cursor.fetchone()

        if result == None:
            sessions[username] = None
            raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('/')
        else:
            username = result[0]
            sessions[username] = uuid4() 
            
            # Redirects to user page
            raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('/user/')
```

Then the /user page is loaded and in the client side this code is executed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        let username = sessionStorage.getItem('username'); 
        var myObject = { "username": username};

        $.get("/user/auth", JSON.stringify(myObject),
        function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
});
```

How to get the username here from the GET call to return the approriate access token?

```
    @cherrypy.expose
    def auth(self):
        # get username and if login was successful return access token
        res = {"authentication": "Ok", "token": uuid4()}

        cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        return json.dumps(res).encode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the information as a parameter (no need to stringify the js object):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        let username = sessionStorage.getItem('username'); 
        var myObject = { "username": username};

        $.get("/user/auth", myObject,
        function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
});
```

Receive the parameter in your method:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def auth(self, username):
    # get username and if login was successful return access token
    res = {"authentication": "Ok", "token": uuid4()}
    cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    return json.dumps(res).encode('utf8')
```

Or better using `cherrypy.tools.json_out` (no need to directly convert to json or set the content type):

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def auth(self, username):
    # get username and if login was successful return access token
    return {"authentication": "Ok", "token": uuid4()}
```